# Vista UAC for DLL

Tags: windows-vista

I want to provide Administrator priviliage to my dll for vista.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Process loading the Dll with administrator privileges.

Update:

You could try for a manifest.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation

Answer (score 0):

same as in exe files

set it to what you want in your manifest file

`< requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker|highestAvailable|requireAdministrator"
uiAccess="true|false"/ />`